# Get counts of categorical factors across multiple variables/columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

I have the following minimal example in R:

```
testing = data.frame(c("Once a week", "Once a week", "Rarely", "Once a month", "Once a month"), c("Once a month", "Once a month", "Once a week", "Rarely", "Rarely"))
colnames(testing) = c("one", "two")
testing

        one          two
1  Once a week Once a month
2  Once a week Once a month
3       Rarely  Once a week
4 Once a month       Rarely
5 Once a month       Rarely
```

I want the end result to be a dataframe that has all the possible categorical factors in one column and the rest of the columns are the counts for each column/variable like this:

```
categories    one    two
Rarely        1      2
Once a month  2      2
Once a week   2      1
```

I have no restrictions on R libraries so whatever would be the easiest here (maybe `plyr`/`dplyr`?).

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Table works with no need for outside packages:

```
sapply(testing, table)
#             one two
#Once a month   2   2
#Once a week    2   1
#Rarely         1   2
```

Comment: OP requests a data.frame, while this looks like a matrix. Might want to coerce or something.

Comment: @Frank Agreed. OP can make it into any useful format desired

Comment: Thanks, I'll just throw an `as.data.frame` around it. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could tidy your table with `tidyr` and `dplyr` packages and count categories with base `table` function

```r
testing = data.frame(c("Once a week", "Once a week", "Rarely", "Once a month", "Once a month"), c("Once a month", "Once a month", "Once a week", "Rarely", "Rarely"))
colnames(testing) = c("one", "two")
testing
#>            one          two
#> 1  Once a week Once a month
#> 2  Once a week Once a month
#> 3       Rarely  Once a week
#> 4 Once a month       Rarely
#> 5 Once a month       Rarely

library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

testing %>%
  gather("type", "categories") %>%
  table()
#>      categories
#> type  Once a month Once a week Rarely
#>   one            2           2      1
#>   two            2           1      2

# or reorder colum before table
testing %>%
  gather("type", "categories") %>%
  select(categories, type) %>%
  table()
#>               type
#> categories     one two
#>   Once a month   2   2
#>   Once a week    2   1
#>   Rarely         1   2
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way utilizing `tidyr::gather`, `tidyr::spread`, and `dplyr::count`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

testing %>%
  gather(measure, value) %>%
  count(measure, value) %>%
  spread(measure, n)

# Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
# 
#          value   one   two
#          (chr) (int) (int)
# 1 Once a month     2     2
# 2  Once a week     2     1
# 3       Rarely     1     2
```

Also, see this [fantastic gist](https://gist.github.com/jennybc/04b71bfaaf0f88d9d2eb) on this topic.